# Am I double taxed on a lease buyout?

Tags: united-states, car, sales-tax, auto-leasing, illinois

I'm considering buying my car at the end of its lease.  In looking at the paperwork, I paid the State of Illinois 7% sales tax on the entire negotiated value of the car, not just the portion I leased.

If I were to buy the car I already paid sales tax on, is Illinois going to charge me the sales tax for the residual value a second time?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this site](http://www.crowehorwath.com/insights/tax-alert/tax-news-highlights-motor-vehicle-leases.aspx):

> Currently, lessors who paid tax on previously leased property
>   (including vehicles) are entitled to a credit for the amount of sales
>   tax paid when the vehicle later is sold to an Illinois customer.

Illinois law apparently changed recently, so for new lessees, they are only taxed on the lease payments, not the full value of the new car.

For people who leased previous to this change, yes they were taxed twice on the vehicle: first for the full agreed-upon price, then a second time on the residual value when the lease was bought out.